# Is it mandatory in Spring specify an id for each declared bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubt to the following question finded on this old exam mock (this is related to the Spring v3 and now there is the v4 but I think that many topics are the same).

Given the following Spring configuration file, what is the correct answer:

```
<bean class ="com.spring.service.MyServiceImpl">
    <property name="repository" ref="jpaDao" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.spring.repository.JpaDao"/>
```

1. The first declared bean MyServiceImpl is missing an id must be named myService.
2. The second declared bean JpaDao is missing an id must be named jpaDao
3. Answers 1 and 2 are both rights
4. Answers 1 and 2 are both wrong

My original idea is that both the answer are right because both the bean have no id specified so if it is true that the second bean need an **id=jpaDao** because the first one use it as reference I thought that also the first been need an id. Otherwise how can it be called? (also in the code from the factory?)

But reading the anser finded into the mock it say that the right answer is the second.

So what it means? that in Spring is not mandatary specify an id for each bean? If it is true how can I referer or instantiate the first bean using the factory if it have no id? What am I missing?

Tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky question. Spring knows to create IDs automatically by default. So, the following definitions is correct:

```
<bean class="com.spring.repository.JpaDao"/>
```

But autimalically create bean ID is fully qualified class name. However your first bean refers to bean with ID `jpaDao`. This means that you need such bean. The way to ensure this is to define id explicitly:

```
<bean id="jpaDao" class="com.spring.repository.JpaDao"/>
```

This is the reason that only second answer is correct.

Comment: Using Java configuration is often more convenient than using XML. Simply mark your method with `@Bean` and the class with `@Configuration`. Method's name will become bean name unless you override it via annotation parameter. Since you have to name the method anyway, this pretty much makes the choice of using IDs or not irrelevant.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski, I can't agree more.